# In C++, is there an equivalent of "source" in R?

Tags: c++, r

In the R programming language, I have been using `source()` to load a saved script. Is there a similar way of doing this in C++? (for calling lines of C++ code).

Comment: do you mean `#include` ???

Comment: does that work in the same way as source? i.e. can you put it in half way through a script and it will just start from there?

Comment: @user2432701: yep. #include is a direct placement of the file specified in #include into your current file at the spot specified.

Comment: Please do not do this. Compiled C++ source files are linked together, not `#include`d into one huge file. If you `#include` implementation files you'll cause confusion when you have learnt more and come back to the code. `#include` should only be used for headers. (Until you start writing templated code.)

Comment: And you shouldn't even do `source()` in R. The proper way to organize code is in a package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), whereas C++ is a [compiled language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language). This means that the source code will not be run interactively. Loading and running source code on the fly from your IDE is something that is not possible, except during debugging ("edit-and-continue").

However, there are some recent projects that try to add an interactive layer on top of C++, e.g. [Cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) and the [Projucer](http://cppnow.org/session/the-projucer-live-coding-with-c-and-the-llvm-jit-engine/). In other compiled languages such as the D programming language (a cousin of C++), source code can be [directly run](http://dlang.org/rdmd.html) from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ and other compiled languages, each source file is compiled into an intermediate form. A *linker* combines these intermediates into the final executable (or library.) Code from one file 'uses' code in another by first calling an interface defined in 'header' files (which declare methods and/or classes), then linking chunks of compiled code ('object files') together.

Separating source code into distinct files has two benefits. First, code can be arranged so that each file contains a logical subset of the whole, making life easier for the programmer. Secondly, each source file can be handled separately by the compiler, giving efficiencies in space (the compiler can deal with more code in total than would fit in memory in a single file) and time (the compiler can selectively re-compile a single changed source file rather than the whole programme.)

It is possible to combine source by including (with `#include`) all source files into one big source file. If you do this you lose at least the second benefit above.

Answer (score 0):

Not in standard C++. The closest equivalent is loading a DLL/.so (library) at runtime. This library can be compiled independently, in theory even after your program has started. But the library must be compiled before it can be loaded, and that must be done by the same compiler that was used to compile the main executable.